# Is it useful to define the hazard function of distributions with support in the real line?

Tags: distributions, survival, hazard

The hazard function is commonly used in models using distributions with positive support (gamma, weibull, lognormal, etcetera). However, I have not seen this concept (hazard) being used in the context of models using distributions with support on the entire real line, like the normal, Student-t, logistic, laplace, etcetera.

Is there any use of the hazard function associated with distributions with support on the real line?

**EDIT**: I just came across the concept of Inverse Mills ratio. It seems like the hazard function of distributions with support of the real line appears, implicitly, through this concept (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @whuber notes in a comment on another answer, there is no reason to restrict hazard functions to distributions having only non-negative support. Although a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) suggests that restriction, a survival function $S(x)$ can be taken in general to be the complement of a corresponding cumulative distribution $F(x)$, with $S(x)=1-F(x)$. For any value of $x$ for which $f(x)$ is defined and $S(x)$ isn't 0, there is a defined value of the hazard $h(x)=f(x)/S(x)$.

A survival function defined over the entire real line can be useful in evaluating a parametric survival model fit, as explained for example in Chapters 18 and 19 of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/parsurv.html). A Kaplan-Meier survival plot of censored, standardized residuals over the real line can help evaluate whether the distribution of residuals matches that expected for a particular choice of parametric family (e.g., standard minimum extreme value, defined over the entire real line, for a Weibull model).

Furthermore, survival analysis with left-censored survival times can be thought of as allowing for negative survival times. In R, a left-censored observation at time $x$ can be coded as `Surv(-Inf, x, event)`.

Survival functions defined over the entire real line thus can be useful.

The question, however, is how useful a *hazard function* is for distributions with support over the entire real line. The hazard function is perhaps most useful as describing the probability of an event at time $x$ given that there hasn't yet been an event. In practice for analysis of event times, it's useful to define a time origin such that $f(x)=0$ (and thus $F(x)=0$) for $x \le 0$. In that case, $h(x)=0$ for $x \le 0$. I suppose there might be circumstances in which a different time origin might make sense, but it's hard to think of one.

Comment: I just came across the concept of Inverse Mills ratio. It seems like the hazard function of distributions with support of the real line appears, implicitly, through this concept (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills_ratio).

Answer (score 0):

The hazard function is a function of time so a non-negative support is required.

In survival analysis, the hazard function is the probability of dying at time $t$ given that you survived until time $t$.

Comment: Your logic is unconvincing, because there's no mathematical obstacle to defining a hazard function for any (absolutely continuous) distribution, nor must people always measure time as positive values.

Comment: @whuber The hazard function can be defined as $$h(t) = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}$$ where $f(t)$ is a probability density function defined on the interval $[0,\infty]$ and $S(t)$ is the corresponding Survival function, i.e. $S(t)=1-F(t)$. 
It does not make sense to perform survival analysis with time being negative.

Comment: Sure it does: it makes perfect sense, and works perfectly well, to shift the time coordinate by any constant amount.  Moreover, that formula for $h$ works provided $f$ exists and $S$ is nonzero; and even for positive random variables it's not defined when $S$ is zero.

Comment: By definition $f(t)$ is on the interval $[0,\infty]$. Using something like a Gaussian would require truncation. Obviously when $S$ is 0 the survival analsyis is complete?

Comment: That's perfectly circular: by *your* definition $f$ has non-negative support, therefore "non-negative support is required"!